# Laravel: how to upload large image with Homestead and Forge

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel on Homestead and Forge, and am uploading images with the Intervention/Image package, and would like to allow user to upload photos from an iPhone where the photos will be larger than 2MB. When I tried to submit the photo I got an nginx error saying the photo was too large.  I understand that I may have to modify the php.ini file to change max_upload_size, since even though I plan on resizing the image before I save it, I assume the photo still has to upload before I can resize it, but is there a good way to do this so that I can make the same change on the Forge and Homestead machines at the same time?  Is there another way to do this that is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a recent upgrade to Forge. If you go to Server -> Meta - there is now a field to change "Max Field Upload Size".

The default is 2 - but you can change it anything.

No need to make any further server config changes - Forge does it all for you.

Comment: what about homestead?